# Temporarily take kubernetes cluster offline

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eks

I have a kuberbetes cluster running in EKS. We use it for testing periodically but mainly it just sits there with all its nodes and costing us.

I am looking for the most elegant way to turn it off so it does not incur costs and turn it back on when needed.

My thought; use eksctl to scale the node group to 0 instances and change it back up when needed.

Is there a more “elegant” way to do this?

Comment: Scaling groups to 0 is really the only way, but you will still continue to pay for the running control plane. You may be better off from a cost perspective to use EKS fargate if your pods/containers don't run for most of the day

Comment: That’s fine. The bulk of the costs are from the nodes